# Purely Solid-State Circuit Withstanding 1kV, able to source 125mA

Tags: high-voltage, solid-state-devices

I'm looking to design a purely solid-state circuit that can perform the following:

> Handle an AC Source with Vpk=1kV and act like an open circuit. (Schematic 1)
> When the source is removed and replaced with a 10Ohm load, source 125mA from a 2.5V Source. (Schematic 2)

I realize the most obvious choice for this problem would be a mechanical relay, but I am trying to find a purely solid-state solution. There are 1.5kV solid state relays (extra 0.5kV is for safety measures), but the highest current I've found for these is 45mA and their internal resistance is too high (300Ohms). Have been simulating various combinations of BJTs, Diodes, and SCRs for about 4 hours so far and still have not been able to find a solution. Main limitation has been that P-Type MOSFETs and BJTs max out at 600V.

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated, and I realize that 'no solution' is a potential answer. Thanks[image: Open Circuit][image]

Comment: Single MOSFETs don't work for AC. They do not block current in both directions. BJTs can block in both directions (I think?), but don't conduct in both directions (but neither are they thyristors only conducting one direction and block in both and are what  is actually used for AC).

Comment: how is the source and resistor switched into, and out of, the circuit? ... it appears to be something already in existence

Comment: Have you considered a *gaseous state* component, i.e. a spark gap or a thyratron? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thyratron and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudospark_switch. These can handle in excess of 100 kv, have low series resistance, and switch in the microsecond region.

Comment: Sounds like what's needed is a window detector centered around/near 0 V and with a few hundred millivolts to either side. Within the window, you bypass the isolation barrier (engage the relay or whatever) and expose the current source (even if the AC source is there but near zero volts output, I suppose.) Outside the window the isolation barrier is engaged (the relay is disengaged.) You don't really need a two-quadrant answer, so a one-quadrant device would do when replacing the relay with a semiconductor device. The problem will be in protecting that device. Or am I missing something?

Comment: How much current can you allow to leak though in the 1 kV AC case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are  [HV BJT Transistor](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/bu508af.pdf),  SiC MOSFETs, IGBTs, [HV Triac](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/240/cla40mt1200npb-1591721.pdf)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqJuHx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>