# Switching n-MOSFET as Solid-State Relay

Tags: mosfet, ac, high-voltage, solid-state-relay

I'm trying to design a simple solid state relay that can be in the off state when an AC Source is applied (schematic one) and then source up to 150mA to a small resistor when that AC Source is removed (schematic two). My one problem here is I cannot seem to turn on the MOSFET with this wiring scheme, as the Gate and Source are shorted. Any ideas on how to fix this? (Can assume DC Source is 2.5V, AC Source is high, up to 1kV peak)

[image]

[image]

Comment: A single MOSFET cannot block current in both directions. They have an parasitic body diode that is anti-parallel to the drain-source inside. A single MOSFET cannot be used for AC. You can, however, use two back-to-back MOSFETs so they each block the current in one direction but this has gate-drive complications.

Comment: Adding the 2nd diode below the MOSFET allows me to block current in both directions. Only problem now is, Vgs is always zero so I can never turn the MOSFET on lol

Comment: where are your specs? bias resistors?

Comment: Break it down into small tasks. AC detect, active low(-ve) with cap filter then self biased FET (+) on but disabled by AC detect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Purely Solid-State Circuit Withstanding 1kV, able to source 125mA](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/515255/purely-solid-state-circuit-withstanding-1kv-able-to-source-125ma) If you have additional information related to your original question, use the "edit" button to add the information there. Do not create a duplicate question.

Comment: Ah ok my bad. They answered my original post, with the solution being using a  MOSFET and two diodes. Now I'm just confused how switching the MOSFET into the 'on' state occurs. Figured that'd be a separate question, didn't want to drag on the post.

Comment: In Figure 6 of this post, for example, how does that photodiode trigger the gates from being 'shorted together,' to turning on the relay? That's really my main source of confusion: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/basics-of-ssr-solid-state-relay-the-switching-device/